# Create a continuous column with repeated cells and calculation in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I try to make some calculations with the following dataset:

```
dataset <- data.frame(specimen = c("NIA","NIA","NIA","MAT","MAT"),
                      brakg = c(9.4,0,0,7.8,0),
                      cebkg = c(0,2.3,3.1,0,2.4),
                      rotkg = c(0,1,1.1,0,1.2),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  specimen brakg cebkg rotkg
1      NIA   9.4   0.0   0.0
2      NIA   0.0   2.3   1.0
3      NIA   0.0   3.1   1.1
4      MAT   7.8   0.0   0.0
5      MAT   0.0   2.4   1.2
```

I want to have the `brakg` variable duplicated, the variables `cebkg` and `rotkg` available and a calculation from `brakg - sum(cebkg)` and `brakg/sum(rotkg)`. This should be the result:

```
specimen    list    value
NIA         Init    9.4
NIA         Eval    9.4
NIA         Ceb     2.3
NIA         Ceb     3.1
NIA         Rot     1.0
NIA         Rot     1.1
NIA         DiffA   4.0
NIA         RateB   4.48
MAT         Init    7.8
MAT         Eval    7.8
MAT         Ceb     2.4
MAT         Rot     1.2
MAT         DiffA   5.4
MAT         RateB   6.5
```

I have tried (without success) this code:

```
spds <- split(dataset, dataset$specimen)
# Splitting the dataset to make an evaluation per specimen

res <- lapply(spds, function(DF){
  i <- which(DF[['brakg']] != 0)
  j <- which(DF[['cebkg']] != 0)
  k <- which(DF[['rotkg']] != 0)
  tmp <- rbind(DF[rep(i, 2), ], DF[j, ], DF[k, ])
  # So I can stack the brakg value repetition... after that null ideas
})
```

Please, any help will be useful, even in base R or Tidyverse (I don't know if tidy functions can output different number of vars). Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain your calculation? It is not clear to me how you get the values in `list` and  `value`.

Comment: Hello @RonakShah, for NIA `DiffA = 9.4 - (2.3+3.1) = 4.0` and `RateB = 9.4/(1.0+1.1) = 4.48`. For MAT `DiffA = 7.8 - (2.4) = 5.4` and `RateB = 7.8 / (1.2) = 6.5`

Comment: @RonakShah and list is a named vector, could be `list = c("Init","Eval",rep("Ceb", length(quantity of non zero cebkg) , rep("Rot", length(quantity of non zero rotkg), "DiffA","RateB")` repeated for each specimen.

Comment: Can there be more than 1 non-zero value in `brakg` for a `specimen` ? If yes, can you include that in the example?

Comment: @RonakShah, no, only one non-zero `brakg` per specimen. By the way if `brakg` is non-zero, then `cebkg` and `rotkg` are 0. And viceversa, if  `cbkg`and `rotkg` are non-zero, then `brakg` is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After splitting you can try with `lapply` to get all the calculation for each `specimen` :

```
spds <- split(dataset, dataset$specimen)
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(spds, function(tmp) {
         vals <- tmp$brakg[tmp$brakg != 0]
         i <- tmp$cebkg != 0
         j <- tmp$rotkg != 0

   data.frame(specimen = tmp$specimen[1], 
         list = c("Init","Eval",rep("Ceb", sum(i)), 
                  rep("Rot", sum(j)), "DiffA","RateB"), 
         value = c(rep(vals, 2), tmp$cebkg[i], tmp$rotkg[j], 
                   vals - sum(tmp$cebkg), vals/sum(tmp$rotkg)))
}))

rownames(out) <- NULL
out


out
#   specimen  list   value
#1       MAT  Init 7.80000
#2       MAT  Eval 7.80000
#3       MAT   Ceb 2.40000
#4       MAT   Rot 1.20000
#5       MAT DiffA 5.40000
#6       MAT RateB 6.50000
#7       NIA  Init 9.40000
#8       NIA  Eval 9.40000
#9       NIA   Ceb 2.30000
#10      NIA   Ceb 3.10000
#11      NIA   Rot 1.00000
#12      NIA   Rot 1.10000
#13      NIA DiffA 4.00000
#14      NIA RateB 4.47619
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ronak Shah, that was a great answer and quite shows the power of vectorized operations in R. I have just a question, this operation can't be performed using tidyverse due to the different lengths of groups in specimens, can it?

Comment: It can be done, there are alternate functions in `tidyverse` which can perform the same calculation. `group_split` + `map` should be able to do it.

Comment: Sounds interesting @Ronak Shah, I'll try to figure out how (guess map is from `purrr`). Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

This code is a little long, but I believe it is clear and easy to debug/edit.

```
DiffA = merge(
            dataset[which(dataset$brakg != 0), c(1, 2)],
            aggregate(cbind(cebkg = cebkg) ~ specimen, dataset[which(dataset$cebkg != 0), c(1, 3)], FUN="sum")
            )

RateB = merge(
            dataset[which(dataset$brakg != 0), c(1, 2)],
            aggregate(cbind(rotkg = rotkg) ~ specimen, dataset[which(dataset$rotkg != 0), c(1, 4)], FUN="sum")
            )

res = rbind(
        # Init
        with(dataset[which(dataset$brakg != 0), ], 
            data.frame(
                    speciment = specimen,
                    list = "Init",
                    val = brakg
                )
        ),
        # Eval
        with(dataset[which(dataset$brakg != 0), ], 
            data.frame(
                    speciment = specimen,
                    list = "Eval",
                    val = brakg
                )
        ),
        # RateB
        with(RateB, 
            data.frame(
                    speciment = specimen, 
                    list = "RateB",
                    val = brakg / rotkg
                )
        ),
        # DiffA
        with(DiffA, 
            data.frame(
                    speciment = specimen, 
                    list = "DifA", 
                    val = brakg - cebkg
                )
        ),
        # Ceb
        with(dataset[which(dataset$cebkg != 0), ], 
            data.frame(
                    speciment = specimen,
                    list = "Ceb",
                    val = cebkg
                )
        ),
        # Rot
        with(dataset[which(dataset$rotkg != 0), ],
            data.frame(
                    speciment = specimen,
                    list = "Rot",
                    val = rotkg
                )
        )
)


> res
   speciment  list     val
1        NIA  Init 9.40000
2        MAT  Init 7.80000
3        NIA  Eval 9.40000
4        MAT  Eval 7.80000
5        MAT RateB 6.50000
6        NIA RateB 4.47619
7        MAT  DifA 5.40000
8        NIA  DifA 4.00000
9        NIA   Ceb 2.30000
10       NIA   Ceb 3.10000
11       MAT   Ceb 2.40000
12       NIA   Rot 1.00000
13       NIA   Rot 1.10000
14       MAT   Rot 1.20000
```